# ROS2 Python quaternion to euler

Tags: python, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS community,

I am trying to use the function "quaternion to euler" using python for ROS2 eloquent, but I can not import the right library.

Here there is not example related to that: https://github.com/ros2/geometry2

I really appreciate if you could guide me.

BR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355794/ros2-python-quaternion-to-euler/) by [sbalmagro](https://answers.ros.org/users/54335/sbalmagro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2020-06-25

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone who stumbles upon this in the future, now there is a function available in the tf_transformations library called euler_from_quaternion in ROS2 Humble and above.

You can use it by importing it first `from tf_transformations import euler_from_quaternion`

Then convert the quaternion to roll, pitch, yaw by

`orientation_list = [orientation_q.x, orientation_q.y, orientation_q.z, orientation_q.w]`

`(roll, pitch, yaw) = euler_from_quaternion(orientation_list)`

`self.pose_yaw = yaw`

---

Originally posted by [rros](https://answers.ros.org/users/53403/rros/) with karma: 26 on 2022-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may be looking for the transformations.py file that is associated with tf.  Here is an issue explaining why it doesn't exist in tf2:

https://github.com/ros/geometry2/issues/222

---

Originally posted by [nsprague](https://answers.ros.org/users/2815/nsprague/) with karma: 228 on 2020-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leuko](https://answers.ros.org/users/57019/leuko/) on 2020-12-26**:
TL/DR: ros2 should stay lightweight. An idea is to package [transforms3d library](https://matthew-brett.github.io/transforms3d/) for ROS2 like [it was done for kinetic](https://github.com/dronecrew/transforms3d-release).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if @nsprague's answer does not satisfy you, and you do not want to use transforms3d library, you can also implement the function yourself:

https://automaticaddison.com/how-to-convert-a-quaternion-into-euler-angles-in-python/

---

Originally posted by [leuko](https://answers.ros.org/users/57019/leuko/) with karma: 71 on 2020-12-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PaddyCube](https://answers.ros.org/users/40932/paddycube/) on 2021-01-11**:
Hello,
I read since hours about this topic but I'm totally lost now. I need a way to build a Quaternion from Euler in Python for ROS2 Foxy as my IMU Sensor only provide YPR as Euler. Do I really need to build a method in Python to do this by my own? Is there really no build-in functionality I can use?
I found some example using c++ there they build a Quaternion by something like:

q =  tf2::Quaternion()
q.setRPY(r, p, y)

Is there no equivalent in Python for this? I can'T find any example on this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you very much for all the replies.

As a workaround, I have found an implementation of the transformations:

https://gist.github.com/salmagro/2e698ad4fbf9dae40244769c5ab74434

---

Originally posted by [sbalmagro](https://answers.ros.org/users/54335/sbalmagro/) with karma: 51 on 2021-01-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1